# Code for loading a picture from any folder to data report

Tags: report, reporting-services

I know how to embede pictures to the data report but I need to load custom pictures on the data report chosen by user from any folder.
Please advise how to do it.

Thanks and best regards,

Furqan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a **ReportParameter** to the report.
2. Then in the Image property dialog (as shown below) set the image source as **External** and in the "Use this image" field, mention the report parameter.

[image]